# How can I compile pacat-simple.c?

Tags: compiling, pulseaudio, gcc, header-file

I want to try writing some code to do audio playback with pulseaudio. There is a simple example program included in the official docs: [pacat-simple.c](https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/doxygen/pacat-simple_8c-example.html).

I made sure the `libpulse-dev` package was installed, and confirmed that the pulse headers `#include`d in in that program were actually present in `/usr/include/pulse`. I then copied the `pacat-simple.c` file that was in `/usr/share/doc/libpulse-dev/examples/`, to another folder since I plan to plat with it a little to see how things work. (This file was actually slightly different from the version I linked above, but whatever.)

Since I was unable to find any specific instructions for that example file, I thought it might be as simple as:

```
gcc pacat-simple.c
```

but that gave me the following error message from the linker:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cciylcLH.o: in function `main':
pacat-simple.c:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to `pa_simple_new'
/usr/bin/ld: pacat-simple.c:(.text+0x113): undefined reference to `pa_strerror'
/usr/bin/ld: pacat-simple.c:(.text+0x15b): undefined reference to `pa_simple_read'
/usr/bin/ld: pacat-simple.c:(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `pa_strerror'
/usr/bin/ld: pacat-simple.c:(.text+0x1f2): undefined reference to `pa_simple_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

After a bit of searching, I found an [old forum post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1585012) that suggested adding the following flags `-lpulse-simple -lpulse` to link to those `.so` files. In retrospect it makes sense I would need to do that.

So, I tried running

```
gcc -lpulse-simple -lpulse pacat-simple.c
```

but I got the same error message show above (with a different temp file name of course). Is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: Does `gcc pacat-simple.c -lpulse-simple -lpulse` work any better?

Comment: ... see for example [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Huh, that compiles an `a.out` file for me successfully, but if I run it, or pipe `/dev/random` into it then I get no sound. Maybe I just need to read the source code more carefully.

Comment: @steeldriver Ah, okay. If I understand that answer correctly, `gcc` is trying to figure out the dependency graph from the order the flags are in. I was not aware it did that!

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
gcc pacat-simple.c -lpulse-simple -lpulse
```

"successfully" gave me an executable that if passed the filename of a sound file it would play a a garbled mess into the speakers. But if I pass the same filename into the real `pacat` then I usually (but not always!) get similar results. (sometimes the newly compiled executable stops sooner and prints out `pa_simple_write() failed: Invalid argument`. But for now I'm assuming this indicates a different issue with my system.

Comment: The message `pa_simple_write() failed: Invalid argument` may indicate that the supplied data is not of an acceptable length. While testing it is tempting to just specify a random file which is not an audio file. The PulseAudio example uses 16-bit samples and 2 channels, so whatever file is supplied must have a length which is a multiple of 4 bytes.